# Caracter "coringa" como critério de uma query

Tags: mysql, query

Estou tentando criar um motor de seleção de critérios de consulta. Por exemplo:

Eu tenho uma massa de dados aonde existes as seguintes variáreis:

1. código da loja
2. Estado brasileiro em que se encontra
3. Região brasileira em que se encontra
4. Bandeira de produtos que a loja distribui
5. data da venda
6. valor

O campo que eu desejo retornar é o de valor, desde que um ou mais dos critérios acima tenha(m) sido satisfeito(s). Eu não queria criar todas as variedades de combinações possíveis entre esses 5 campos. Então eu queria saber:

É possível usar caracteres coringa (tipo *) como critérios de consulta?

Aí eu poderia definir as variáveis da seguinte forma:

```
if(isset($_GET['uf'])){ // Estado brasileiro
    $uf = $_GET['uf'];
} else {
    $uf = "*"; 
}
if(isset($_GET['rg'])){ // Região brasileira
    $rg = $_GET['rg'];
} else {
    $rg = ""; 
}

if(isset($_GET['ini']) && $_GET['fim'] ){ // data incicial
    $ini = $_GET['ini'];
} else {
    $ini = "01/01/2017"; 
    $fim = date("d-m-Y");
}
if(isset($_GET['band'])){ // bandeira
    $band = $_GET['band'];
} else {
    $band = "*"; 
}
```

E depois montar uma consulta única que possa atender à qualquer critério setado ou não:

```
$qry = "SELECT sjy_grupo.id_grupo, sjy_empresas.bandeira AS id_bandeira, sjy_bandeira.bandeira
        FROM sjy_bandeira INNER JOIN 
             sjy_grupo INNER JOIN sjy_empresas ON sjy_grupo.id_grupo = sjy_empresas.grupo
        AND sjy_bandeira.id_bandeira = sjy_empresas.bandeira
        WHERE id_grupo = '$grupo'
        AND id_bandeira = '$id_bandeira'
        GROUP BY sjy_grupo.id_grupo, sjy_bandeira.id_bandeira, sjy_bandeira.bandeira";
```

Comment: Os caracteres coringa seriam por conta de WHERE id_grupo = '$grupo' AND id_bandeira = '$id_bandeira', certo?

Comment: Exatamente Brunno. Eu quero justamente evitar o trabalho de ter de criar uma query para cada possibilidade de combinações entre essas variáveis

Comment: Se a resposta ajudou você, favor aceita-la como correta

Comment: @brunno não encontrei aonde aceita como correta

Comment: logo abaixo do título da minha resposta, do lado esquerdo, tem duas setinhas e um sinal de "check", que fica verde quando você coloca o mouse em cima.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O caracter coringa existe e é o `"%"`. Ele deve ser usado em conjunto com a palavra LIKE no lugar do sinal de igualdade (`=`) (conforme apontado em comentário.

Dito isso, ressalto que seria ruim usar caracteres coringa nesse tipo de query. Isso porque se por acaso você precisar usar caracter coringa de propósito, vai ter um problema. Outro motivo é que ele pode trazer valores acidentalmente indesejados.

Na minha visão, é melhor verificar a existência de valor nessas variáveis.

```
$qry = "SELECT sjy_grupo.id_grupo, sjy_empresas.bandeira AS id_bandeira, sjy_bandeira.bandeira
    FROM sjy_bandeira INNER JOIN 
         sjy_grupo INNER JOIN sjy_empresas ON sjy_grupo.id_grupo = sjy_empresas.grupo
    AND sjy_bandeira.id_bandeira = sjy_empresas.bandeira";

if (isset($grupo)) {
    $qry .= " WHERE id_grupo = '$grupo'";
}

if (isset($id_bandeira)){
    $qry .= " AND id_bandeira = '$id_bandeira'";
}

$qry .= " GROUP BY sjy_grupo.id_grupo, sjy_bandeira.id_bandeira, sjy_bandeira.bandeira";
```

Comment: Somente pra complementar, caso prefira utilizar o coringa ``%``, ele deve ser usado em conjunto com a palavra **LIKE** ao invés do **IGUAL**. Ex.: 

``WHERE uf LIKE "%SP%" ``

Comment: @CleberGriff Sim, bem apontado. Editei a resposta.

Comment: Obrigado senhores